# How do you convert an int to it's respective ASCII letter in C?

Tags: c, string, integer, cs50

I'm challenged myself to make program where it takes an int and it has to print the respective ASCII letter, like this: if the number is 65, it should print out `A` and so on. But I don't know how to do this. This is my code so far:

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 65; i < 81; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", i);
    }

}
```

I need to add some kind of function in the spot between `string b = NULL;` and `printf("%s\n", b);` but I don't know which function I should use. In the end, it should print out all the letters of the alphabet in order and each one has it's own line. If you happen to know a function that can help me, please tell me.

P.S

If I do it like my example above, I get the following error messages:

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    try.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o try
try.c:12:18: error: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Werror,-Wformat]
  printf("%s\n", i);
          ~~     ^
          %d
1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'try' failed
make: *** [try] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this:

```
int integer = // your int ;
char c = integer;
```

It is very simple and makes it a char.

Also, you can check the result using `isascii` from `<ctype.h>`

Comment: That won't change the parameter mismatch and is not needed at all.

Answer (score 2):

> In the end, it should print out all the letters of the alphabet in order and each one has it's own line.

You don't really need a function to do that. Also `string` is wrong choice as you only wanted to print character. This `for` probably does what you hoped to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
{
    printf("%c\n", i + 'a');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont think you need anything. It should automatically print the integer as a char when you day %s.

Simply do:

````
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{

  printf("%s\n", i);
}```
````

Comment: I meant that I wanted to convert it like this: if the int is 65 then it should print out the letter A, because in aschii the number 65 is equivalent to the letter A

Comment: "It should automatically print the integer as a char when you day %s." Where did you get that? As you can clearly see in the error message in the question, passing an `int` while using `%s` is not a good idea. It will use the number as an address and start reading characters from that memory location. Thats undefined behaviour and chances are high that you will end up with a segfault.

Comment: That is how it works. All you have to do is try running this and you will I am right.